# "Client Authentication" certificate for iPhone for school Wi-Fi

Tags: iphone, wifi, ssl

My school Wi-Fi, which requires that I log in using my username and password, requires that I accept this certificate (which I think might be a trusted root certificate?) in order to connect:

[image]

What does this allow them to do? Does this certificate mean they can run man in the middle attacks and decrypt my HTTPS searches?

Help is very much appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Although a very good question, this is off topic in my opinion because the answer to it applies to all devices not just Apple ones. This is not your fault, with out knowing the answer its difficult to tell whether it applies to all devices. Take a look here→ https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178909/my-school-wifi-asks-to-trust-a-certificate-on-iphones-does-it-this-allow-the/180815#180815

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer to it applies to all devices not just Apple ones. An almost identical question can be found on InfoSec.

Comment: I did +1 it though!

Answer (score 1):

This certificate only *identifies* your device as a trusted *known* device and to be allowed on the network.

Credentials (usernames and passwords) can be stolen.  Hardware identifiers (MAC addresses) can be spoofed.  This *unique* certificate gets generated at the time of request is and cannot be spoofed.  So, even if someone steals your username and password and tries to access the network using their MacBook, it won't allow them onto the network.

It's a cert for *authentication*, not encryption/decryption.